# QGIS set raster No-Data value

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, nodata

I have a raster layer that resulted from a series of calculations with

1. raster calculator (simple subtraction of two raster layers)
2. `gdal_translate -ot Int16 -of GTiff ...` (convert to `Int16`, as the result of above is in `Float32`)

however the `gdal_translate` command seems to forfeit the No-Data information. It ("correctly") assigns minmal values to the previously no-data cells (−32,768 in case of Int16), however doesn't store the No-Data information in the metadata (as seen in Properties of the raster layer, see picture).

Previous layer, result from raster calculator:
[image: RasterLayer properties showing No-Data value (minimal possible value of Float32)]

Problematic layer, result from `gdal_translate` with no No-Data value:
[image: RasterLayer properties showing No-Data: n/a]

As a result, the values are displayed as regular raster cells by default. I'm aware that I can adjust styling and `clip out of range values` in styling options to make the "−32,768-No-Data"-cells invisible again. **But I'd rather have the raster layer remember, which cell values correspond to "No-Data"!**

I tried to assign it with the gdal command:
`gdal_translate -a_nodata -32.768 -ot Int16 -of GTiff ...` 
however that shows no effect.

**Can I manually set a No-Data-Value via Properties or some other tool?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving a raster layer (Right click on layer > `Export` > `Save as ...`) you have the option to set No-Data values (see yellow circle in picture). This will have the desired effect.

As an additional hint since we're talking about conversion from `Float32` to `Int16`: Don't forget to check Compression options, since they are not always on by default (see red arrow in picture).

[image: set No-Data value in "Save Raster Layer as..." dialog]